# How to implement add & remove recipients from Asp.Net GridView to TextBox using CheckBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, textbox

I'm stuck into this problem where on a **web application**, I'm uploading contacts and retrieving them into a **GridView**. I'm using **CheckBoxes** to select or deselect the **mobile numbers** from the **Gridview** and **storing the selected numbers into a multiline TextBox separated with commas ","** to send **multiple SMS**. Now, the problem is that I'm not able to remove the added numbers or string from the **TextBox** when I'm **unchecking** the **CheckBoxes** in the **GridView**. Please help me through this problem. It's eating my time up!!
**Thanks in advance..**
Below is my code:

```
protected void chkboxSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool SomethingChecked = false;
    CheckBox ChkBoxHeader = (CheckBox)gvcntct.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkboxSelectAll");
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvcntct.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkEmp");
        if (ChkBoxHeader.Checked == true)
        {
            ChkBoxRows.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ChkBoxRows.Checked = false;
            TextBox2.Text = "";
        }            
    }
    if (!SomethingChecked)
    {
        TextBox2.Text = "";
    }            
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove a specific number from the `TextBox` with `CheckBox` and there could be multiple numbers?

Comment: yes exactly....

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the unchecked ID text from the `TextBox2` by using:

```
TextBox2.Text.Replace(string.Format(", {0}", ID), "");
```

Here's the complete code (Note I reomved some unnecessary code your'e using, like the 3rd `else` statement which can never be reached, since a checkbox is either `true` or `false`):

```
protected void chkboxSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    CheckBox ChkBoxHeader = (CheckBox)gvcntct.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkboxSelectAll");
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvcntct.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkEmp");
        ChkBoxRows.Checked = ChkBoxHeader.Checked;        
    }
}

protected void chkEmp_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox CheckBox1 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)CheckBox1.NamingContainer;
    Label lblUser = (Label)row.FindControl("lblMake");
    string ID = row.Cells[2].Text;

    if (TextBox2.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        string[] Ids = TextBox2.Text.Split(',');

        if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            TextBox2.Text += string.Format(", {0}", ID);
        }
        else if (CheckBox1.Checked == false)
        {
            CheckBox ChkBoxHeader = (CheckBox)gvcntct.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkboxSelectAll");
            foreach (GridViewRow rows in gvcntct.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)rows.FindControl("chkEmp");
                ChkBoxHeader.Checked = false;
                ChkBoxRows.Checked = false;
                TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text
                                   .Replace(string.Format(", {0}", ID), "")
                                   .Replace(string.Format("{0}", ID), "");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
            int index = 0;
            foreach (string s in Ids)
            {
                if (!s.Equals(","))
                {
                    TextBox2.Text += string.Format("{0},", Ids[index]);
                }

                index++;
            }
            if (TextBox2.Text.Contains(","))
            {
                TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace(string.Format(", {0}", ID), "");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TextBox2.Text = ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Output screen :** **https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B3Cbp2qGm506Q3B0OUVxTEFfTms?usp=sharing** but the first number **checked** still remains even after unchecking & I think that's because the last number remaining doesn't contain `(string.Format(", {0}", ID), "")` any solution for that would help me a lot!!

Comment: OK I think I found the problem, i updates the `chkEmp_CheckedChanged` method. Please check now.